# Unable to connect HP ALM API via google script

Tags: rest, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, alm

I'm trying to call HPQC API to get some reports but I'm not able to get the QCsession cookie when I call /qcbin/rest/site-session. I successfully authenticated with /qcbin/authentication-point/authenticate but I'm stuck in the next phase.

Not that I can use the API without any trouble with Postman, but my Google script doesn't work.

Here's a look at the call I'm doing :

```
var headers = { "Accept":"application/xml", 
"Content-Type":"application/xml", 
"method": "POST",
"headers" : {"Authorization": digestfull },
"muteHttpExceptions": true 
};


var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,headers);
var cookie = resp.getAllHeaders();//['Set-Cookie'];//.split(';')[0].toString(); 
Logger.log(cookie);
//Get session cookie
param = "/hp/rest/site-session";
var url2 = hpqc + param + api_key;
var payload = "<session-parameters><client-type>REST Client</client-type></session-parameters>";
var headers2 = { "Accept":"application/json", 
"Content-Type":"application/xml", 
"method": "POST",
"muteHttpExceptions" : true,
"cookie" : cookie,
"body" : payload
};

resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2,headers2);
```

The first call works fine, but the second gives me the following response :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Error 401 Authentication failed. Browser based integrations - to login append '?login-form-required=y' to the url you tried to access.</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 401</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /qcbin/rest/site-session. Reason:
<pre>    Authentication failed. Browser based integrations - to login append '?login-form-required=y' to the url you tried to access.</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/>
```

It seems that the cookies aren't correctly sent.

Can you please help me find what is wrong with my code ? I'm sorry if it's too obvious, I'm learning to use google script.

Thank you

Comment: The second parameter/argument to urlFetch.fetch() is a options argument not headers. Review documentation.

Comment: This doesn't change anything, it's just the name of the variable. Weither it is called "options" or "header" it is built as in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the following code

```
var payload = "<session-parameters><client-type>REST Client</client-type></session-parameters>";
var headers2 = { "Accept":"application/json", 
"Content-Type":"application/xml", 
"method": "POST",
"muteHttpExceptions" : true,
"cookie" : cookie,
"body" : payload
};
```

with this and it worked

```
var payload = "<session-parameters><client-type>REST Client</client-type></session-parameters>";
var headers = {// "accept":"application/json", 
                  //"contentType":"application/json", 
                  "method": "POST",
                  "muteHttpExceptions" : true,
                  "headers" : {
                    "Content-type" : "application/xml",
                    "Accept" : "application/json",
                    "Cookie" : cookie
                  }, 
                  "payload" : payload
                 };
```

Thank you TheMaster for giving me the hint !!